# Send data to new activity from listview JSON from mysql

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview

```
I use bundle before but it only return null,
 how can i get the name of the student_name that populated from database using json of the clicked item and show it into new activity?

 public void ListDrawer() {
    final List<Map<String, String>> studentList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("student_info");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jsonChildNode.optString("student_name");
            String number = jsonChildNode.optString("student_id");
            String outPut = name + "-" + number;
            studentList.add(createStudent("Students", outPut));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 ////////////////////////////////// UPDATE LISTVIEW ITEMS ONCLICK

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //Do your logic for getting the student variables here
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this,Profile.class);

            intent.putExtra("student ", String.valueOf(id));

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

//////////////////////////////////////UPDATE
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, studentList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[] { "Students" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  Above is mylistview and my onItemClicked function

  i use json to retrieve the list of students from mysql and view it in listview and now im trying to pass data from the selected student in listview to new activity

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc56O.jpg
```

Comment: did you get student id you passed from intent in Profile activity ?

Comment: the code you are using is not much preferable so use pojo class to store data and retrieve the data from those global variables.use adapter class to display the data then you can send the data from one class to another class

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki nope, student_id is stored in mysql and im fetching from there to view in student list activity.

Comment: @brahmyadigopula oh i see ill look into that thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add on @brahmyadigopula comment, using `POJO` is way more simpler and if you are already using JSON as preferd way, you can use Googles library for transforming `JSON strings` in to `Objects` with one line of code.

https://github.com/google/gson

Then you can just transform the object into JSON String with the same library and pass it through the Intent as String and 'catch' it in the Activity as a string and transform it back to an Object and use it as you'd wish.

It would look something like this:

`public class User {
   private String name;
   private String number;
   (getters/setters)
}`

And then in your adapter you would do:
`User user = new Gson().fromJson(jsonMainNode, User.class);`
so you can then have a cleaner code when getting the data. So when passing the data with an intent you can just transform the `User` object to string by doing this: `String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(user);` and pass it through the intent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For your adapter, you're using "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" as a layout for your list items. This will give you a simple TextView as a result and this TextView will contain the whole student information (name-number) as a full String variable.
I have 3 solutions for your problem :

1- Get the text of the item TextView and use split function to get the students info as follows :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //Get the item full text content
            String studentInfo = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            //Split using the space " "
            ArrayList<String> studentInfoArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(studentInfo.split(" ")));

            //Split using the dash "-"
            String lastObject = studentInfoArray.get(studentInfoArray.size() - 1);
            ArrayList<String> lastObjectInfoArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(lastObject.split("-")));

            //Rearrange the student name
            //Sometimes the name is composed of more than two words
            String studentName = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < studentInfoArray.size() - 1; i++) {
                studentName += " " + studentInfoArray.get(i);
            }
            studentName += " " + lastObjectInfoArray.get(0);

            //Create the intent to start the Profile activity
            //Add student info to extras
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this,Profile.class);
            intent.putExtra("studentName", studentName);
            intent.putExtra("studentID", lastObjectInfoArray.get(lastObjectInfoArray.size() - 1));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

2- Create a custom layout for your ListView adapter that will contain 2 TextViews in a LinearLayout, One for the name and One for the number. Then, you can easily get each info separately like this :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //Get the list item subviews using IDs of the custom item layout
        TextView tvStudentName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvStudentName);
        TextView tvStudentNumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvStudentNumber);

        //Create the intent to start the Profile activity
        //Add student info to extras
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this,Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("studentName", tvStudentName.getText());
        intent.putExtra("studentID", tvStudentNumber.getText());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

3- Make your student list as a global variable, then just get the info directly from the array :

```
public class MainPage extends Activity {

//Declare studentList as a global variable
List<Map<String, String>> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
.
.
.

//Change the structure of your ListDrawer method
public void ListDrawer() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("student_info");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jsonChildNode.optString("student_name");
            String number = jsonChildNode.optString("student_id");

            //Add the student info to a new Hashmap object
            //Add the student to the array
            Map<String, String> studentInfo = new HashMap<>();
            studentInfo.put("student_name", name);
            studentInfo.put("student_id", number);
            studentList.add(i, studentInfo);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Then, send data to Profile activity :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //Create the intent to start the Profile activity
        //Add student info to extras
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this,Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("studentName", studentList.get(position).get("student_name"));
        intent.putExtra("studentID", studentList.get(position).get("student_id"));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Finally, to retrieve the info sent from MainPage Activity to Profile Activity :

```
public class Profile extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .
    .

    Log.e("EXTRA", "Student Name : " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("studentName"));
    Log.e("EXTRA", "Student ID : " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("studentID"));
}
}
```